# Change the border color of the select input for focus

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to change the focus color of my select input, I'm pretty confused as to what I should override.

```css
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: inherit;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.forma #kome {
  border-color: #8e8e8e;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align-last: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: transparent url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mahm0udwally/all-flat/16/User-icon.png") no-repeat 15px center;
}

.forma select :focus {
  border-color: #2a6dc9 !important;
}
```

```html
<form class="center-block forma" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="kome" name="kome">
            <option value=" disabled selected ">Choose</option>
            <option value="smth"> smth </option>
            <option value="smth2"> smth2 </option>
        </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be no space between `select` and `:focus` selectors. Space denotes parent-child relationship, i.e. "focused child of select". While `select:focus` means `AND`: focused select.

```css
.forma select:focus {
    border-color: #2a6dc9 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me with chrome, by changing the border-style to insset, and then whatever outline-color you want.  It does not change the focus color on the options, but it does at least change the focus color when you tab to it.

```
select {
   border-style: inset;
   outline-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: A little late but thanks mate :D The comment above found my error

Answer (score 0):

to style select child on focus :

change

```
.forma select :focus{
    border-color: #2a6dc9 !important;
}
```

with

```
.forma option:hover{
    border: 1px solid red ;
}
```